# How to cancel redirection of terminal in code?

Tags: c, operating-system, programming-languages

I tried to know how to cancel redirection but I couldn't.
If I enter ./program < input.txt to redirect stdin
, Is there anyway to make stdin read from keyboard in C program code after reading all lines of input.txt?

Comment: This post could benefit from some more details such as operating system, language, etc.and consider using tags to improve quality of the question

Comment: On Windows VC it is simple because you can use `getch()` and `cscanf()` for console input, and `cprintf()` and `cputs()` for console output. Anything else can be with the usual `stdin` and `stdout` functions which can be redirected. This is particularly useful if the output of a slow program is redirected to a file while progress cues can be seen on the console.

Comment: @WeatherVane: However, using `getch` and `cscanf` do not redirect `stdin` as the question requests. E.g., if the program wishes to call code that reads from `stdin` and have it read from the terminal, the fact that `getch` reads from the console would be inadequate. Possibly a solution would involve closing `stdin` and explicitly opening `/dev/tty` on Unix or the similar thing on Windows. (`CON:`?)

Comment: Opening dev/tty means freopen("/dev/tty", "r", stdin)?